# Why is the second S silent in "Sens dessus dessous"?

Tags: prononciation

The expression "sens dessus dessous" is pronounced as "sans dessus dessous" or "sang dessus dessous". But I have yet to find another sentence where "sens" is pronounced that way. I always find it pronounced with the S being non-silent. Such as "les cinq sens".

I am wondering why, then, would the second S in "sens dessus dessous" be silent?

Comment: Very interresting question as a lot of natives would certainly fail to write it correctly exactly because of this specificity

Comment: @LaurentS. In my experience, a lot of natives know how to spell it but actually fail to pronounce it correctly!

Comment: @ArnaudMortier As far as natives are concerned there are just "different pronunciations" and they are all equally correct, it just depends where you live. A lot of very learned people pronounce /sɑ̃s/ and perfectly know how to write it.

Comment: @Laure Aren't they all "correct" simply because everything becomes correct when a large enough proportion of natives make the same mistake? (That's my interpretation even though I just learned yesterday that /sɑ̃/ is how you should say it, as supported by the etymology provided here).

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Just don't tell someone from the south of France they do not pronounce "correctly" because in the south we tend to pronounce all the letters, and they have done that for centuries. Neither Paris nor the Académie Française dictate the people how to pronounce, thinking that Paris or the Académie Française is "more correct" is discriminating.

Comment: @Laure I wouldn't go that far. Getting one word wrong and having a completely different set of habits consistently across the whole language are different things, and I do believe that the latter deserves the utmost respect. I understand only now what you meant to say in your first comment.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier No problem. We agree then !

Answer (score 14):

It seems that the reason for this unique pronunciation would be the ancient form of the word "sens"; this is suggested by the [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sens_dessus_dessous);

> « sens » dans cette locution vient de « c’en » et il est prononcé \sɑ̃\, d’où une fréquente confusion avec « sans ».

This is confirmed by the etymology in the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sens) ;

> Les loc. adv. sous B (**sens dessus dessous, sens devant derrière**)¹, sont prob. dues à des altér. graph. d'apr. « sens » de « sen », lui-même altér. de « cen », contraction de « ce en » (cf. sen dessus dessouz, mil. XVe s., CHARLES D'ORLÉANS, Rondeaux, 98, éd. Champion, p. 404; c'en dessus dessoubz, 1511, GRINGORE, Farce à la suite du Jeu du Prince des Sots, éd. D'Héricault et Montaiglon, t. 1, p. 281). En a. fr. et m. fr., on rencontre les formes « ce devant derriere » (1268, Claris et Laris, 11802 ds T.-L., s.v. devant), « ce dessus dessoubs » (1342, JEHAN BRUYANT, Pauvreté et Richesse, 30b, ibid., s.v. desus).

¹<sub>Addition by user **LPH**</sub>

Comment: Littré est une autre source intéressante, étayée de nombreux exemples et incluant un commentaire de l'auteur: [chez Gallica](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54066991/f504.item.r=%22cen%20dessus%20dessous%22), [chez littre.org](https://www.littre.org/definition/sens%20dessus%20dessous.2)

Answer (score 10):

According to ["l'Académie Française"](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/sens-dessus-dessous-tourner-les-sangs), it's because of the earlier use of it "*ce en*" (ce **qui est** en) dessus dessous, meaning "*what is upside down*".

"*Ce en*" is then pronounced like "cent / sang / sans".

Answer (score -1):

Le mot "sens" se prononce /sãs/ ... dans l'expression "sens dessus dessous" le "s" final de "sens" se prononce. Ce n'est pas une question de liason avec le mot qui le suit. C'est une simple question de comment prononcer le mot "sens" correctement. C'est une question de phonologie, non pas d'étymologie.

Comment: D'accord avec toi, les deux prononciations s'entendent, avec ou sans /s/, /sãsdəsydəsu/ ou /sãdsydsu/.  Je me demande même si la première n'est pas plus répandue que la prononciation traditionnelle.

Comment: "*dans l'expression "sens dessus dessous" le "s" final de "sens" se prononce.*" - c'est très très très bizarre, car je ne l'ai au contraire **jamais** entendu prononcer, d'où la confusion de nombreuses personnes lorsqu'il faut l'écrire, et la transcription "sonore" du mot, avec une faute. Vous êtes sûr de vous là ? Ou c'est une faute de frappe ?

Comment: @petitrien Entièrement d'accord, je n'ai jamais prononcé /sã/ comme la plupart des gens que je côtoie et si quelqu'un me disais que je ne prononce pas « correctement » (pour reprendre un terme lu sur cette page que je trouve tout à fait discriminant car c'est quoi la correction ? l'académie française ? ) je lui dirais que sa prononciation est pédante.

Comment: @OneMoreTimeButAnonimously. Il arrive assez souvent que coexistent une prononciation orthographique et une prononciation dite traditionnelle.  Par exemple, au grand dam /ogrãdam/ ou /ogrãdã/, gageure /gaʒœʀ/ ou /gaʒyʀ/, sans parler des toponymes, Cassis /kasi/ ou /kasis/…

Comment: @OneMoreTimeButAnonimously Petit test (réduit, donc pas de valeur statisque) autour de moi. Accent **parisien : [sɑ̃ ˌdsyˈdsu]** presque **[sɑ̃ˌsyˈdsu]** le premier /d/ étant très peu perceptible, les parisiens (et les gens du nord en général) ayant tendance à avaler des consonnes. Accent du **sud-ouest** où on prononce (encore, la prononciation ayant tendance à s'uniformiser avec les moyens de communication modernes) la plupart des consonnes **[ˌsɑ̃sdəˌsydəˈsu]**. Ce n'est ni Paris ni l'Académie Française qui dicte la prononciation, toutes les prononciations sont respectables.

Comment: @petitrien : super, merci pour les exemples, ils sont clairs et je suis 100% d'accord, mais ce n'est pas ce que je comprends de la réponse (est-ce que c'est l'idée de cette réponse d'ailleurs ?). D'où ma confusion :)

Comment: @Laure: je suis sûr que si je fais le test j'ai des résultats identiques ou approchants, j'ai déjà entendu ces différences dans la vie et les régions. Comme commentaire à @ petitrien, je ne saisis pas le "sansse"  de la réponse d'origine :) ça doit venir de moi mais j'essaie de comprendre...

Comment: @OneMoreTimeButAnonimously. Je comprends la réponse comme voulant dire que "sens" dans "sens dessus dessous" se prononce toujours  /sãs/, ce qui est faux.  La question et les autres réponses laissaient peut-être entendre que "sens" se réalisait toujours comme /sã/ dans cette expression, ce qui serait faux également.  Il était bon que quelqu'un rappelle que  /sãs/ est une prononciation acceptable.  C'est pour ça que j'ai mis un vote positif.

Comment: Ha ok ! C'est cela l'explication. Merci d'avoir clarifié. Peut-être que l'auteur ajoutera cette précision pour les "durs de l'oreille" comme moi :)